# can not access outer once i use mdDiloag in angular meterial

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

i'm trying to open dialog box using angular material mdDialog with one text box and drop down field but once it open it can not access outer scope data.
my code is

```
$scope.ouetButton=function(){
$mdDialog.show({
            scope: $scope.$new(),
            templateUrl: "printDialog.html"
});

// Button click in templete
$scope.closeDialog = function(sheetout, reason, teststartTime) {
    $mdDialog.hide();
    var sheets = $scope.sheets;
    console.log("i got this value undifined ",sheets );
}
}
```

if i use some paramater like

```
$scope.ouetButton=function(){
$mdDialog.show({
            scope: this,
            templateUrl: "printDialog.html"
});

// Button click in templete
$scope.closeDialog = function(sheetout, reason, teststartTime) {
    $mdDialog.hide();
    var sheets = $scope.sheets;
    console.log("i got this value fine",sheets );
}
}
```

than it get value of sheets but after close it i can not click again on 
    `$scope.ouetButton`

Comment: I think you don't need to use `array[i].date_created` just use `i.date_created`

Comment: i got undefined if i use  for(i in array) 
        {
            console.log(i.date_created);
        }

Comment: @AndriKurnia That isn't right; `for ... in` loops yield each _index_, not each _element_. @AlexKumbhani, your snippet is correct; something else is wrong in code you haven't shown us. Please edit to include _all_ relevant code; see [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please look it again i edit it

Comment: @qxz ah my bad, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: For the record, a [`for ... of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (ES6) will give you each element in an array/iterable object.

Comment: @AlexKumbhani Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a JSON string (e.g., from reading a file) into an actual JavaScript object, use [`JSON.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Here is an example:

```
fs.readFile('data.txt', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var array = JSON.parse(data); // converts the JSON string into an actual object/array
    // use array as you did in your question...
});
```

BONUS: Use a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to process each *element* of the array:

```
for (var obj of array) {
    console.log(obj.date_created);
    // etc.
}
```

Note that this is only available since ECMAScript 6, but since you're using Node.js, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This file contains a `VALID JSON STRING`, so just read the file and do JSON.parse(), and then you can do anything else with the JSON object.